# javascript search for asp.net gridview

Tags: javascript, search, gridview

I would like to search an asp.net gridview using a textbox. I would like to call a javascript function that would eliminate all of the records where the string is contained in any of the records of the specified column. This is the easiest way I can think of doing this, not sure if there is an easier way.